# Alternatives for insert ignore into for SQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

i just switched over from a Mysql server to SQL server. But i just found out that `INSERT INGORE INTO` doesn't work with sql server. 
Original code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO DATA_EXACT_INVENTORY_LOCATIONS (ID, Code, Opslaglocatie, Omschrijving, OpVoorraad)
          VALUES ('$inventorylocationID','$inventorylocationsItemCode','$inventoryStorageLocationsCode','$inventorylocationsItemDescription','$inventorylocationsCurrenctStock')
```

I found out that i can use `on duplicate key update`, but the problem is that i have sql query's with upto 50 variables. So to use on duplicate key update would be alot of work. So what i was wondering is there a better alternative for `INSERT IGNORE INTO` that's is just plug and play so i don't have to write all variables again.

Comment: Use a merge statement or code your front end to catch and ignore the PK violation. Kinda raises the question why you're getting these errors though; your concurrent use strategy probably needs some improvement - i'd have said "ignore" was one of the worst things to do with data you're trying to insert. ps; i don't think SQLS has  `on duplicate key update`

Comment: So a merge statement is the way to go, but all the info i can find on merge just shows that merge can be used to compare two tables to each other and then update, delete etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
INSERT DATA_EXACT_INVENTORY_LOCATIONS (ID, Code, Opslaglocatie, Omschrijving, OpVoorraad)
    SELECT ID, Code, Opslaglocatie, Omschrijving, OpVoorraad
    FROM (VALUES ('$inventorylocationID', '$inventorylocationsItemCode', '$inventoryStorageLocationsCode', '$inventorylocationsItemDescription', '$inventorylocationsCurrenctStock')
         ) V(ID, Code, Opslaglocatie, Omschrijving, OpVoorraad)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM DATA_EXACT_INVENTORY_LOCATIONS deil
                      WHERE deil.id = v.id -- or whatever column gets the duplicate key
                     );
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite the code to use `MERGE`.  The `SELECT` should work in both databases.

Let me also add that you should learn to use parameters.  Munging query strings with constant values exposes your code to SQL injection attacks and to hard-to-debug syntax errors.